# Permission denied error while uploading file on flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, backend

I was a making a website for a grocery store using flask. I wanted to add a feature in which the owner of the website could add products using the dashboard provided in the website. I had planned to ask owner about the product name, price, image and category in which the product will be added. But when I tried to upload the image in my uploads folder than an error saying 'Permission Denied' came.

This is my application structure:

```
|-- .gitignore
|-- ATTRIBUTIONS
|-- package-lock.json
|-- package.json
|-- run.py
|-- .vscode
|   |-- settings.json
|-- views
    |-- account.py
    |-- addDashboardCategory.py
    |-- addDashboardProduct.py
    |-- cart.py
    |-- category.py
    |-- checkEmail.py
    |-- checkout.py
    |-- dashboard.py
    |-- dashboardCategory.py
    |-- dashboardProduct.py
    |-- database.db
    |-- editDashboardCategory.py
    |-- editDashboardDetails.py
    |-- editDashboardProduct.py
    |-- editProfile.py
    |-- home.py
    |-- login.py
    |-- logout.py
    |-- makeURLName.py
    |-- models.py
    |-- orders.py
    |-- product.py
    |-- removeDashboardCategory.py
    |-- removeDashboardProduct.py
    |-- search.py
    |-- signup.py
    |-- viewOrder.py
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- static
    |   |-- css
    |   |   |-- account.css
    |   |   |-- account.css.map
    |   |   |-- account.scss
    |   |   |-- addDashboardProduct.css
    |   |   |-- addDashboardProduct.css.map
    |   |   |-- addDashboardProduct.scss
    |   |   |-- cart.css
    |   |   |-- cart.css.map
    |   |   |-- cart.scss
    |   |   |-- category.css
    |   |   |-- category.css.map
    |   |   |-- category.scss
    |   |   |-- checkout.css
    |   |   |-- checkout.css.map
    |   |   |-- checkout.scss
    |   |   |-- common.css
    |   |   |-- common.css.map
    |   |   |-- common.scss
    |   |   |-- dashboard.css
    |   |   |-- dashboard.css.map
    |   |   |-- dashboard.scss
    |   |   |-- dashboardCategory.css
    |   |   |-- dashboardCategory.css.map
    |   |   |-- dashboardCategory.scss
    |   |   |-- dashboardProduct.css
    |   |   |-- dashboardProduct.css.map
    |   |   |-- dashboardProduct.scss
    |   |   |-- editDashboardProduct.css
    |   |   |-- editDashboardProduct.css.map
    |   |   |-- editDashboardProduct.scss
    |   |   |-- editProfile.css
    |   |   |-- editProfile.css.map
    |   |   |-- editProfile.scss
    |   |   |-- footer.css
    |   |   |-- footer.css.map
    |   |   |-- footer.scss
    |   |   |-- form.css
    |   |   |-- form.css.map
    |   |   |-- form.scss
    |   |   |-- home.css
    |   |   |-- home.css.map
    |   |   |-- home.scss
    |   |   |-- loader.css
    |   |   |-- loader.css.map
    |   |   |-- loader.scss
    |   |   |-- login.css
    |   |   |-- login.css.map
    |   |   |-- login.scss
    |   |   |-- navbar-message.css
    |   |   |-- navbar-message.css.map
    |   |   |-- navbar-message.scss
    |   |   |-- navigation-bar.css
    |   |   |-- navigation-bar.css.map
    |   |   |-- navigation-bar.scss
    |   |   |-- orders.css
    |   |   |-- orders.css.map
    |   |   |-- orders.scss
    |   |   |-- product.css
    |   |   |-- product.css.map
    |   |   |-- product.scss
    |   |   |-- signup.css
    |   |   |-- signup.css.map
    |   |   |-- signup.scss
    |   |   |-- viewOrder.css
    |   |   |-- viewOrder.css.map
    |   |   |-- viewOrder.scss
    |   |   |-- _colorcode.scss
    |   |-- img
    |   |   |-- cancel.png
    |   |   |-- company-logo.png
    |   |   |-- contact.png
    |   |   |-- dashboard.png
    |   |   |-- grocery-items-main-background-image.jpg
    |   |   |-- product-img.jpg
    |   |   |-- search.png
    |   |   |-- shopping-cart.png
    |   |   |-- success.png
    |   |   |-- user.png
    |   |   |-- warning.png
    |   |-- js
    |   |   |-- dashboardCategory.js
    |   |   |-- delete-dashboard-category.js
    |   |   |-- edit-dashboard-category.js
    |   |   |-- modal-animation-dashboard.js
    |   |   |-- navbar-message.js
    |   |   |-- product.js
    |   |   |-- responsive-navigation-bar.js
    |   |   |-- showMessage.js
    |   |-- responsive
    |   |   |-- account.css
    |   |   |-- account.css.map
    |   |   |-- account.scss
    |   |   |-- cart.css
    |   |   |-- cart.css.map
    |   |   |-- cart.scss
    |   |   |-- category.css
    |   |   |-- category.css.map
    |   |   |-- category.scss
    |   |   |-- checkout.css
    |   |   |-- checkout.css.map
    |   |   |-- checkout.scss
    |   |   |-- dashboard.css
    |   |   |-- dashboard.css.map
    |   |   |-- dashboard.scss
    |   |   |-- dashboardCategory.css
    |   |   |-- dashboardCategory.css.map
    |   |   |-- dashboardCategory.scss
    |   |   |-- dashboardProduct.css
    |   |   |-- dashboardProduct.css.map
    |   |   |-- dashboardProduct.scss
    |   |   |-- editProfile.css
    |   |   |-- editProfile.css.map
    |   |   |-- editProfile.scss
    |   |   |-- form.css
    |   |   |-- form.css.map
    |   |   |-- form.scss
    |   |   |-- home.css
    |   |   |-- home.css.map
    |   |   |-- home.scss
    |   |   |-- login.css
    |   |   |-- login.css.map
    |   |   |-- login.scss
    |   |   |-- navigation-bar.css
    |   |   |-- navigation-bar.css.map
    |   |   |-- navigation-bar.scss
    |   |   |-- orders.css
    |   |   |-- orders.css.map
    |   |   |-- orders.scss
    |   |   |-- product.css
    |   |   |-- product.css.map
    |   |   |-- product.scss
    |   |   |-- signup.css
    |   |   |-- signup.css.map
    |   |   |-- signup.scss
    |   |   |-- viewOrder.css
    |   |   |-- viewOrder.css.map
    |   |   |-- viewOrder.scss
    |   |-- uploads
    |-- templates
    |   |-- account.html
    |   |-- addDashboardProduct.html
    |   |-- base.html
    |   |-- cart.html
    |   |-- category.html
    |   |-- checkout.html
    |   |-- dashboard.html
    |   |-- dashboardCategory.html
    |   |-- dashboardProduct.html
    |   |-- editDashboardDetails.html
    |   |-- editDashboardProduct.html
    |   |-- editProfile.html
    |   |-- home.html
    |   |-- login.html
    |   |-- orders.html
    |   |-- product.html
    |   |-- search.html
    |   |-- signup.html
    |   |-- viewOrder.html
    |-- uploads
    |-- __pycache__
        |-- .pyc files here
```

`run.py`:

```
from views import createApp # Importing createApp from __init__.py file in views directory

app = createApp() # Creating app using function createApp from __init__.py file in views directory

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=5001) # Runs Server at port 5001
```

`__init__.py` file in `views` directory:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path # Importing Path from os module to check path of database
from flask_login import LoginManager # Importing Class LoginManager to manage Login Details

db = SQLAlchemy() # Creating Database Instance
DATABASENAME = 'database.db' # This is the name of the database that the website will be using
app = Flask(__name__) # Initializing Flask Module
UPLOAD_FOLDER = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), 'uploads') # Making variable for storing path of uploads folder
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'sjdflksajflksajfsajflksajl' # Setting up the secret key for the application
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DATABASENAME}'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'}


def allow_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


def createApp():
    ''' This function will create the app '''
    db.init_app(app) # Adding App in Database

    from .home import home # Importing home from home.py which will help us to address the '/' route of the website

    from .category import category

    from .product import product

    from .account import account

    from .orders import orders

    from .viewOrder import viewOrder

    from .cart import cart

    from .editProfile import editProfile

    from .checkout import checkout

    from .login import login

    from .signup import signup

    from .dashboard import dashboard

    from .editDashboardDetails import editDashboardDetails

    from .dashboardCategory import dashboardCategory

    from .addDashboardCategory import addDashboardCategory

    from .dashboardProduct import dashboardProduct

    from .editDashboardProduct import editDashboardProduct

    from .addDashboardProduct import addDashboardProduct

    from .editDashboardCategory import editDashboardCategory

    from .removeDashboardCategory import removeDashboardCategory

    from .search import search

    from .logout import logout

    app.register_blueprint(home,url_prefix='/') # Registering Blueprint so that all '/' requests are redirected to code of home.py

    app.register_blueprint(category,url_prefix='/category') # Register blueprint to access /category route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(product,url_prefix='/product') # Register blueprint to access /product route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(account,url_prefix='/account') # Register blueprint to access /account route of the website 

    app.register_blueprint(orders,url_prefix='/orders') # Register blueprint to access /orders route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(viewOrder,url_prefix='/viewOrder') # Register blueprint to access /viewOrder route of the website 

    app.register_blueprint(cart,url_prefix='/cart') # Register blueprint to access /cart route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(editProfile,url_prefix='/editProfile') # Register blueprint to access /editProfile route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(checkout,url_prefix='/checkout') # Register blueprint to access /checkout route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(login,url_prefix='/login') # Register blueprint to access /login route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(logout,url_prefix='/logout') # Register blueprint to access /logout route of the website
    
    app.register_blueprint(signup,url_prefix='/signup') # Register blueprint to access /signup route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(dashboard,url_prefix='/dashboard') # Register blueprint to access /dashboard route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(dashboardCategory,url_prefix='/dashboard/dashboardCategory') # Register blueprint to access /dashboard/dashboardCategory route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(addDashboardCategory,url_prefix='/dashboard/dashboardCategory/addDashboardCategory') # Register blueprint to access /dashboard/dashboardCategory/addDashboardCategory route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(editDashboardCategory,url_prefix='/dashboard/dashboardCategory/editDashboardCategory') # Register blueprint to access /dashboard/editDashboardCategory route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(removeDashboardCategory,url_prefix='/dashboard/dashboardCategory/removeDashboardCategory') # Register blueprint to access /dashboard/removeDashboardCategory route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(dashboardProduct,url_prefix='/dashboard/dashboardProduct') # Register blueprint to access /dashboard/dashboardProduct route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(editDashboardProduct,url_prefix='/dashboard/editDashboardProduct') # Register blueprint to access /dashboard/editDashboardProduct route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(editDashboardDetails,url_prefix='/dashboard/editDashboardDetails') # Register blueprint to access /dashboard/editDashboardDetails route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(addDashboardProduct,url_prefix='/dashboard/addDashboardProduct') # Register blueprint to access /dashboard/addDashboardProduct route of the website

    app.register_blueprint(search,url_prefix='/search') # Register blueprint to access /search route of the website    

    createDatabase(app) # Running createDatabase function to create database if it doesn't exists

    loginManagerVariable = LoginManager() # Initialising Login Manager
    loginManagerVariable.login_view = 'login.loginUser'
    loginManagerVariable.init_app(app)

    from .models import User # Importing User Class from models.py

    @loginManagerVariable.user_loader
    def loadUser(userName):
        return User.query.get(str(userName))

    return app # Returning App so that it could run in main.py

def createDatabase(app):
    ''' This function will create database for the website '''
    if not path.exists('views/' + DATABASENAME): # If database doesn't exists
        db.create_all(app=app) # Creating Database
        print('Created Database!')
```

`addDashboardProduct.py` in the `view` directory

```
from flask import Blueprint,render_template,request,flash,redirect # Importing Blueprint to handle routes related to addDashboardProduct page
from flask_login import current_user
from .models import Category,Product # Importing Category and product from models.py to get information about Category and products
import uuid
import os
from . import app,db,allow_file
from .makeURLName import makeURLName # Importing makeURLName function to make url compatible name for given entries
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

addDashboardProduct = Blueprint('addDashboardProduct',__name__,static_folder='static',template_folder='templates') # Creating a Blueprint so that it could be accesed from files from outside

@addDashboardProduct.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def renderAddDashboardProductPage():
    ''' This is the function that will run when someone called for '/' route '''

    if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.userId == 'owner':

        if request.method == 'POST':

            if 'profileImage' not in request.files:
                flash('No file part',category='error')
                return redirect(request.url)
            file = request.files['profileImage'] # Getting Profile Image
            if file.filename == '':
                flash('No image selected for uploading',category='error')
                return redirect(request.url)
            
            if file and allow_file(file.filename):
                productImageName = f'{uuid.uuid4().hex}_{secure_filename(file.filename)}' # Getting the hex value to keep it as filename of choosed file
                productId = str(uuid.uuid1()) # Getting string value of a uuid to use it as a product id
                productName = request.form['name'] # Getting product name
                productPrice = request.form['productPrice'] # Getting product price
                productURLName = makeURLName(productName) # Getting a url compatible name for the product
                categoryIdOfProduct = request.form['categoryIdOfProduct'] # Getting category Id of which the product is
                categoryObject = Category.query.filter_by(categoryId=categoryIdOfProduct).first() # Getting the category which's having the id as choosed in form
                categoryName = categoryObject.categoryName # Getting the name of the category
                categoryURLName = categoryObject.categoryURLName # Getting the url name of the category

                try:
                    # open('b',os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']), productImageName).close()
                    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']), productImageName) # Saving given file
                    productObject = Product(productId=productId,productName=productName,productURLName=productURLName,productImageName=productImageName,productPrice=productPrice,categoryId=categoryIdOfProduct,categoryName=categoryName,categoryURLName=categoryURLName) # Filling object to add it to database
                    db.session.add(productObject) # Adding it to the database
                    db.session.commit() # Commiting to database
                    return redirect('/dashboard')
                except Exception as e:
                    flash(f'Some Error {e}',category='error')
                    return redirect(request.url) # Redirecting to the same page as
            else:
                flash('Only files with extention jpg,jpeg and png are allowed',category='error')
                return redirect(request.url)

        return render_template('addDashboardProduct.html',title='Add Product - TB Grocery Store',user=current_user,categories=Category.query.all()) # Rendering addDashboardProduct.html page
```

### models.py

```
from . import db # Importing db variable to create database models from __init__.py
from flask_login import UserMixin # Importing UserMixin from flask_login module for login in users

# Creating Users Model for database
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    ''' This Model will store users data in database '''
    # Adding Columns
    userId = db.Column(db.String(10000),primary_key=True,unique=True)
    realNameOfUser = db.Column(db.String(250),nullable=False)
    emailOfUser = db.Column(db.String(250),nullable=False,unique=True) #Adding unique=True to add only unique emails in database
    passwordOfUser = db.Column(db.String(1000),nullable=False)
    houseNumber = db.Column(db.String(1000),nullable=False)
    residenceName = db.Column(db.String(10000),nullable=False)
    cityName = db.Column(db.String(3000),nullable=False)
    pincode = db.Column(db.String(1000),nullable=False)
    stateName = db.Column(db.String(5000),nullable=False)
    countryName = db.Column(db.String(5000),nullable=False)
    mobileNumber = db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False)

    def get_id(self):
        ''' This function will override the default properties of get_id under the User Class '''
        return (self.userId)

class Category(db.Model):
    ''' This model will store all the categories of the website '''
    categoryId = db.Column(db.String(10000),nullable=False,primary_key=True,unique=True)
    categoryName = db.Column(db.String(1000),nullable=False)
    categoryURLName = db.Column(db.String(1000),nullable=False)

class Product(db.Model):
    ''' This model will store all the products of the website '''
    productId = db.Column(db.String(10000),nullable=False,primary_key=True,unique=True)
    productName = db.Column(db.String(1000),nullable=False)
    productURLName = db.Column(db.String(1000),nullable=False)
    productImageName = db.Column(db.String(10000),nullable=False)
    productPrice = db.Column(db.String(100000),nullable=False)
    categoryId = db.Column(db.String(10000),nullable=False) # This will be the Id of the category of which the product is
    categoryName = db.Column(db.String(1000),nullable=False)
    categoryURLName = db.Column(db.String(1000),nullable=False)

class Cart(db.Model):
    ''' This model will store all the items of cart of the website '''
    userId = db.Column(db.String(10000),nullable=False)
    productId = db.Column(db.String(10000),nullable=False)
    productQuantity = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
    itemId = db.Column(db.String(10000),nullable=False,primary_key=True,unique=True)
    cartId = db.Column(db.String(10000),nullable=False) # This is the id of all cart in which products are there different Items may have same cartId and if so then it means these items are in same cart
    cartActive = db.Column(db.String(10),nullable=False) # This column will either take True or False. If True it means that cart has not been bought yet and if False it means user has bought the cart

class Order(db.Model):
    ''' This model will contain all the data related to a any order that user has made'''
    orderNumber = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False,unique=True,primary_key=True) # This is the number of the order
    userId = db.Column(db.String(10000),nullable=False) # This will be the Id of user who has made this order
    orderId = db.Column(db.String(10000),nullable=False,unique=True) # This will be a unique Id of the order
    cartId = db.Column(db.String(10000),nullable=False) # This is the id of the cart that has been bought to make this order happen
    paymentMethod = db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False) # This will store the payment method
    date = db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False) # This is the date at which order was placed

''' HOW THE MODEL WILL WORK '''
'''
There are 5 Models in which User,Category and Product Model will store info about respective things
and Cart Model will store userId to know who's cart is it, productId to now what is the product of one item with quantity to know how much is the product and cartId to identify unique Carts and cartActive to
know wether a cart is active or has been bought.
Once somebody buys a cart it becomes unactive and a new cart is assigned to the user
The 5th Model is Order Model which will store info about orders made in entire website. Order Model will
contain 5 Columns which are OrderNumber to know which order is it,userId to know who has made the order,
OrderId to know uniquely identify an order, cartId to know of which cart is this order which cart was
bought to make the order happen and finally date to know when was the order made.
Date will be in form dd-mm-yyyy
'''
```

[Click here](https://github.com/harshu-prasad/Online-Grocery-Store-Using-Flask) to get complete code of the project on Github

Comment: Does the user running the application have permission to write to the uploads directory?  Note if your code is being run in a webserver like Apache or Nginx there may be restrictions on which directories are writeable, regardless of permissions.

Comment: Not all users can add products in database, only the owner of the website has this access. I had tried to add products after logging in as the owner. And I was executing the code in my local computer only